# Spring Websocket: how to subscribe to a topic and fetch the last message?

Tags: spring-websocket, stomp

I have the following spring websocket stomp client:

```
var client = new StandardWebSocketClient();

WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(client);
MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
converter.setObjectMapper(mapper);
stompClient.setMessageConverter(converter);

StompSessionHandler sessionHandler = new StompSessionHandler() {
    @Override
    public void afterConnected(final StompSession session, final StompHeaders connectedHeaders) {

      session.subscribe("/topic/senha", this);
    }
    ...

    @Override
    public void handleFrame(final StompHeaders headers, final Object payload) {
        //get notification here
    }
};

stompClient.connect(uri.toString(), sessionHandler);
```

Server:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(final MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(final StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws");
    }

}
```

I get notified in `handleFrame` about new messages.

But the topic has messages in it's history.

I want to fetch the last message/state from the topic when connected. How to do it?